# url rewrite - any way to write common rule for all my web page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am developing a web site. Here I have implemented the URL rewrite in .htaccess. 
I have a common dynamic variable (?offset=1 ) for all pages
e.g.

```
domain/manageZone.php?offset=1
domain/manageState.php?offset=1
domain/manageCity.php?offset=1
Etc
```

I have successfully implemented the clean URL for the zone page. See my code

```
RewriteRule manageZone-offset-(.*)\.html$ manageZone.html?offset=$1 
RewriteRule manageZone-offset-(.*)\.htm$ manageZone.php?offset=$1
```

I know it's possible to add this on each page i.e.

```
RewriteRule manageState-offset-(.*)\.html$ manageState.html?offset=$1   
RewriteRule manageState-offset-(.*)\.htm$ manageState.php?offset=$1
```

But is there is any way to write common rule for all this pages?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you rewriting .html pages to `.html?offset=...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule manage([a-z]+)-offset-(\d+)\.html?$ manage$1.php?offset=$2 [NC]
```